# GitHub for Windows - How to delete a repo on my local computer?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repo, now I want to delete the clone on my local computer and clone it again in a different place on the same drive. When I select the remote repo and click Clone it says: "This repository has already been added."

I manually deleted the folder containing the original repo on my local computer and this problem still happens.

Comment: Where exactly are you clicking on Clone? Are you using some client software? Which one?

Comment: @Juhana   As  I wrote in the title, I am using GitHub for Windows. In the upper left corner of the window there is a + symbol - clicking on that opens a window with all my remote repos in it and there are three choices: Add / Create / Clone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git hub store the  metadata it manage so it think that you have a repository.

Open the Program, delete the reference to the project and clone again.

Another option is to open a git-bash and clone the project from the gitbash.

Github desktop version 3.X added the delete option. IF your software is older simply upgrade it.

Select the branch that you want to delete, go to `Branch` | `Delete Branch`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select Repository / Remove...

The dialog that comes up asks if you want to remove the repository from the app, and also gives you an option to delete the folder by moving it to Recycle Bin.